# Ford-Fulkerson irregularity (multiple vertices vs. backflow)

Tags: java, algorithm, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

I've thus far been working with graphs whose vertices have only one directed edge between them.  For all the examples I've used to test my implementation, the right answer has been produced.  When I use a graph containing vertices which have an edge running both directions, however, I don't produce the right answer.  I've been treating such an edge running backward as the backflow between those two vertices, as it seems that the backflow and a different "pipe" running backward would end up being equivalent.  Is my assumption here wrong?

Comment: Only someone in to the lingo could understand what you mean. On the other hand, this feels like a math question. :)

Comment: Yeah, i.e. not me a few weeks ago haha.  I'm reluctant to post my code at the moment because this relates to a homework question that's still open for submission :-)  I think (and my limited testing implies) that my implementation works for the simple cases they'll be grading (i.e. only one edge between vertices), but the fact that my assumption does seem to be wrong is worrying me about the rest of my implementation.

Comment: Can you include a minimal graph that exhibits the problem? Also, in all probability the problem is in your code; and will be therefore hard to fix without looking at your code...

Comment: I can investigate to try finding a more-minimal example, but for now, this is the graph that I've been using (note that I choose edges differently than in the pdf).

If you give me just a second, I can post a series of pictures of me working through it on a whiteboard.  I chose paths in the same order that my implementation does (and yes, each path does appear to be valid), but other than that, it's all by hand, yet my results agree with the computer's.

http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/chinneck/po/Chapter9.pdf

Comment: Note that in my grid, both an empty cell and an explicit '0' denote the value '0'.  Also, green on the graph is flow, red is backflow.  I neglected to photograph my initial graph with the assumption above  (though all the remaining pictures reflect it), but essentially I'm combining edges running in opposite directions into one 'edge' with flow and backflow.

http://imgur.com/a/20kn5#0

Comment: There are multiple problems with your whiteboard (for example, some paths are taking over their maximum capacity). What data-structures are you using? Is there anything in this question about programming?

Answer (score 3):

The assumption that two edges with capacities 'a' and 'b'  `U--[a]-->V` and `V--[b]-->U` is equivalent to a single edge `U--[a-b]-->V` is incorrect. Assuming a > b, a negative flow of up to -b is legal in the first case, but illegal in the second case.

You can only add up the flow capacities of same-direction edges. In the graph below, adding the two opposite pipes from E to F and F to E makes them vanish from the graph, changing the optimal solution. 
[image]

Comment: I definitely see what you're saying here (and I'll keep that in mind), but when I solve, I rather treat edges U--[a]-->V and V--[b]-->U as one 'edge' with a flow of 'a' and a backflow of 'b'.  I suppose this could really be thought of as two edges.  See my comment above (on the question itself) for my workthrough on the whiteboard.

Comment: Programming-wise, since you seem to use matrix-representations for the graph, I suggest keeping around both the "current-flow" matrix (with current-flow values) and the "original-flow" matrix (setting the original maxima and minima for each edge). There may be more optimal answers, but this one will make things easier to program, at the cost of increased memory consumption. No problems with small graphs (and for big ones, don't use matrices).